# Difference between two dates in php using Leap Year

Tags: php, datetime

Hey I am trying to get total months from two dates in php. I have searched about leap year calculations between two dates everywhere on internet but did not find the answer.

If my input is "2019-01-01" to "2019-03-31" then the result i expected is 3 months but result i get is 2 month.

Following is my code .

```
 $date1 = strtotime("2019-01-01");  
 $date2 = strtotime("2019-02-28");  

 $diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  
 $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  
 $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                           / (30*60*60*24));  

 printf("%d months",$months);
```

where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Understand Your Problem..
Actually the result you are getting is correct,because day ends at night 12pm and you are checking at day time.So until day ends you cant get complete month.If You add one day and check you will get correctly 3 Months

Below I Made Some Changes to Your Code..

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2019-02-28' . ' +1 day'));
$date1 = strtotime("2019-01-01");  
$date2 = strtotime($new_date);  

$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                       / (30*60*60*24));  

printf("%d months",$months);
```

You can Also Get it by Mysql querying to server

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2019-01-01', (SELECT DATE_ADD('2019-02-28', INTERVAL 1 DAY))) as month
```

You can Try it.Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your math calculates the number of months between the two dates, exclusive of the ending month.

Add 1 to the total, like so.

```
 $months = (floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                           / (30*60*60*24))) +1;
```

Comment: sorry for wrong typing. i have updated my question.. if my input is "2019-01-01" to "2019-03-31" i should get 3 months right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```php
$date1 = "2019-01-01";  
$date2 = "2019-02-28";  

$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $timestamp1);
$year2 = date('Y', $timestamp2);

$month1 = date('m', $timestamp1);
$month2 = date('m', $timestamp2);

$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1); 

printf("%d months",$diff);
```

Try it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/496a08612489977e9e23e8ef3ea07ba991bc5e23

Comment: sorry for wrong typing. i have updated my question.. if my input is "2019-01-01" to "2019-03-31" i should get 3 months right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add extra month in your $month variable

```
 $date1 = strtotime("2019-01-01");  
 $date2 = strtotime("2019-03-31");  

 $diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  
 $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  
 $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                           / (30*60*60*24)) +1 ;  

 printf("%d months",$months); //Output : give add one extra
```

OR

```
$date1 = date_create('2019-01-01');
$date2 date_create('2019-03-31');
$interval= date_diff($date1, $date1);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
```

Comment: sorry for wrong typing. i have updated my question.. if my input is "2019-01-01" to "2019-03-31" i should get 3 months right?

Comment: @Indrajeet :  Update my question please check

Comment: i did not get You.